# Detect the end of an async function inside a for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, settimeout

I want to detect the end of an async function inside the for loop in JavaScript.

My code is:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {


     if(end of everything)
     {
      //call xyz()
     }

    }, 5000 * i);
  })(i); 
}
```

Please help me in achieving my target. Thanks

Comment: if i is equal to the length..... A queue would be so much better than all times timeouts

Comment: can you please explain a bit? with example code..

Comment: it's another setTimeout must be wrapped in a Promise question.  really need a good community managed one to link duplicates to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check if `i` is the last index of the array:

```js
 dataPoints = [1, 2, 3]; 
 for (var i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);

     if(i === dataPoints.length - 1) // if i is the last iteration
     {
      console.log('the end');
      //call xyz()
     }

    }, 1000 * i); // changed 5s to 1s for demo
  })(i); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your design you check to see if the timeout is the last one.

```js
function xyz() {
  console.log("done");
}
var dataPoints = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

for (var i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i, dataPoints[i])      
      if (i === dataPoints.length - 1) {
        xyz()
      }
    }, 500 * i);
  })(i);
}
```

You would be better off using a queue

```js
function xyz() {
  console.log("done");
}
var theData = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

function displayData(dataPoints, done) {
  var iteration = 0
  function next() {
    console.log(dataPoints[iteration])
    iteration++
    if (iteration < dataPoints.length) {
      window.setTimeout(next, 1000)
    } else {
      done()
    }
  }
  next()
}

displayData(theData, xyz)
```

Comment: Isn't that logically different than what he has?  The timeouts on his are run in parallel, your second example there is sequential?

Comment: @user120242 um `5000 * i` <-- they are all offset

Comment: You could just also just `map` the `datapoints` to a promise and use `promise.all`

Comment: @epascarello Right, I get that it's technically the same.  But it's not logically the same thing?

Comment: They are not all running at the same time.  Unless the call is not a timeout, not rally in need of a promise, but one could use one.

Comment: @user120242 How is it not the same thing. They all end up running the same time....

Comment: I guess... But, it's like I tell you to line up some sticks one by one, to show how I could have 10 people line up sticks.  Then you just bring me a table with the sticks lined up in position and place them down.  And in this case I can't really even say the code is easier to understand.  Not that I disagree it's a better implementation technically of the same thing in this case

Comment: Also, I know this is a bit of a stretch, because the delay would probably never amount 5s, but _in theory_ some of those  setTimeouts _could_ resolve in a different order if the scheduler gets beat up or messed with somehow.

Comment: @user120242 setTimeout/Interval if never accurate, we all know that.